# How to connect to WebSphere in J2EE client environment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I'm trying to connect to **EJB** on **WebSphere 7.0**. The EJB requires `javax.ejb.SessionContext` and reads Principal from it, so I need to log in before calling it.

I'm using the following code in stand-alone application:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject;
import com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.callback.WSCallbackHandlerImpl;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(System.getProperties());
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("WSLogin",
        new WSCallbackHandlerImpl("myuser","mypass"));
    lc.login();
    WSSubject.setRunAsSubject(lc.getSubject());
    SessionContext sessionContext=(SessionContext) ic.lookup(
        "java:comp/env/sessionContext");
}
```

I've added the entry to my `jmxremote.access`:

> > myuser readwrite

However, I get an exception:

> Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Name space accessor
>   for the java: name space has not been set. Possible cause is that the
>   user is specifying a java: URL name in a JNDI Context method call but
>   is not running in a J2EE client or server environment.    at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable(javaURLContextFactory.java:98)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:82)
>     at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLObject(NamingManager.java:584)
>     at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:533)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:320)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)

What else should I do, to run my code in the 'J2EE client environment' mentionend in the error message?

Comment: Basically that is just a complicated way of saying "your configuration is not correct, fix it". The question is: where are you trying to run this code? In a plain old Java application or in a JEE container?

Comment: @Gimby in POJA, see update

Comment: Okay, so you need to figure out how to properly connect to Websphere from a client application then. I wouldn't know because I don't use it, I would only be able to help you if you were using JBoss. What I do know is that the internet is full of WRONG ways to do it, you need to try examples from different sources to find one that actually works :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize SessionContext with principal when connecting to remote EJB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556906/initialize-sessioncontext-with-principal-when-connecting-to-remote-ejb)

Comment: I think you should stick with your original question instead of posting extended duplicate version. IBM WAS has extensive documentation BTW.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `java:comp`, you would need to package the client application in an .ear and use `launchClient`.  Ultimately, that's just going to use -CCBootstrapHost/-CCBootstrapPort (or defaults) to connect to the target server to look up the EJB, so you could just use the EJB thinclient and use the fully-qualified EJB binding name instead (see the `CNTR0167I` messages in SystemOut.log).

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use the WAS client runtime JARs. WAS_HOME/AppServer/runtimes. You will need the ORB and the other service specific JARs. As an alternative to using launchClient, you can manually specify the context factory you'll be using here:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(System.getProperties());
```

set the

> java.naming.factory.initial

variable (in your system env or in a Properties object) to

> com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory`